# How do I draw a circle on Eclipse for Android Development?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create a circle in Eclipse for Android development and could not find a simple tutorial.  I just started programming for the Android platform.

Comment: I think this question does not show enough research from the OP, and the link with Eclipse sounds irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for creating a circle drawable.  You will place this code in your res folder (with whatever name you wish - mycircle.xml for instance).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
</shape>
```

Then you can reference this drawable, and assign it as a background drawable for any view (which can be done in your layout.xml or within Java).  For example:

textView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.mycircle);

Comment: Does this go in the MainActivity.java?

Comment: No, this is a drawable you will place in your res folder (the main level).  Then you will reference it as a drawable (which you will assign as a background image to any view in your code - or your layout.xml).  Added info to original answer).

Comment: I get a syntax error on setBackgroundDrawable and under the . (period)

Comment: You probably didn't create the drawable resource correctly (or you are not finding the reference).  You should be able to use autocomplete (ie. type R, cntrl-space, then complete drawable, then hit cntrl-space again to get your resource name).  I

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a read on the [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) classes. A canvas object will allow you to render a circle/oval to a surfaceview object which finally gets rendered to the screen.

I hope this helps.